# is it advisable to have every part of a page as a backbone view template?

Tags: backbone.js, uiwebview, underscore.js, backbone-views

Im making a webview app for iOS & Android using Backbone.js. I'm bit new to Backbone
I have seen some examples where they have used backbone's view template for every section of a particular page/view even if those sections are just static texts or images. I'm not sure if thats the right way to do it. In my opinion one should write a view as a template in HTML only if it's going to dynamically change in its presentation, with the help of variables, etc. Otherwise, the usual structuring of HTML elements is good enough.

Pls provide your inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are right. There's no need to put static parts of the page into templates.

Comment: If they're just examples then any 'static' data you see could actually be dynamic in a greater scope. However, you're right that static data and presentation has little need to be generated in views.

Comment: what about views or part of views that are just going to be hidden or shown dynamically? in that case, is it better to use backbone to render/hide(or backbone equivalent of hiding) them or just use jquery hide/show for that?